# sharepoint 2013 jslink override

Tags: sharepoint

The new SharePoint 2013 property on a web part called JSLink allows me to add some override code customise my web part.

How can I pull in libraries like jquery into that code rather than add into the master page or require manual edits to ensure its on the page. I'd like to keep it self contained in the one JSLink js file?

Answer (score 4):

Separate the scripts you need to load by using the pipe | symbol in JSLink e.g. /_layouts/15/jquery-2.0.3.js|/_layouts/15/jquery-ui.js|/_layouts/15/mytemplate.js